Unity creating new audiosources to loop song at a given time has a pause after the first loop
I have a group of songs that I want to be able to loop and switch between smoothly. To do this, I create an audiosource for each song, play them all at once, and slowly change the volumes of each based on which is song is selected. Each song "restarts" at 57.3 seconds by creating a new audiosource. But since the tracks have small fade out portions at the end, they are slightly longer than 57.3 seconds. To solve this I decrease the volume of the original audiosources until they fade out completely.
The issue I'm having is that at the end of the first loop, the songs end slightly earlier than they should be, causing a pause in the music. Any loop after that sounds correct.
using Unity.VisualScripting;
using UnityEngine;

public class MusicManager : MonoBehaviour
{

    [SerializeField] AudioClip[] music;
    //timeToSwitchTracks is how long to wait before looping and is set to 57.3 seconds
    [SerializeField] float timeToSwitchTracks;

    AudioSource[] musicSources;
    AudioSource[] lastMusicSources;
    //selectedMusic determines which song should be audible and which ones should fade out
    int selectedMusic = 0;
    float timeSinceLastLoop = 0;


    private void Awake() {

        musicSources = new AudioSource[music.Length];
        lastMusicSources = new AudioSource[music.Length];

        if(timeToSwitchTracks <= 0) {
            Debug.Log("Invalid time on timeToSwitchTracks in MusicManager");
        }

        createNewAudioSources();

    }


    private void Update() {

        updateVolumes();

        timeSinceLastLoop += Time.deltaTime;

        //if the 57.3 seconds are up, loop the song
        if (timeSinceLastLoop > timeToSwitchTracks) {

            createNewAudioSources();
            //sets the volume of the newly created audiosource to match the old one
            setMusicVolume(lastMusicSources[selectedMusic].volume);

        }

    }


    void updateVolumes() {

        int sign = 1;

        for(int i = 0; i < musicSources.Length; i++) {

            //add to the volume of the selected track, subtract from the volume of all others
            sign = i == selectedMusic ? 1 : -1;

            //increase or decrease the volume of each song based on if its the selected one or not
            musicSources[i].volume = musicSources[i].volume + (Time.deltaTime * sign);
            //music sources that are about to be deleted should slowly be muted
            if (lastMusicSources[i] != null) {
                lastMusicSources[i].volume = lastMusicSources[i].volume - Time.deltaTime;
            }

        }

    }


    //creates and starts playing new audiosources for each song
    //and puts each precious audiosource into lastMusicSources to fade out slowly
    void createNewAudioSources() {
        timeSinceLastLoop = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < musicSources.Length; i++) {

            //songs placed in this array are slowly muted before being destroyed
            lastMusicSources[i] = musicSources[i];

            musicSources[i] = transform.AddComponent<AudioSource>();
            musicSources[i].clip = music[i];
            musicSources[i].volume = 0;

            musicSources[i].Play();

            //the length of each track varies a bit past 57.3 seconds but sound end by 65 seconds
            Destroy(musicSources[i], 65f);

        }

    }


    public void setSelectedMusic(int x) {
        selectedMusic = x;
    }


    public void setMusicVolume(float volume) {
        musicSources[selectedMusic].volume = volume;
    }


}

I think the issue might be something to do with the timeSinceLastLoop variable not being synced up with the first time the audiosources start playing. I logged out this variable every time the songs looped and the timing was correct. I'm not sure how I could check if the audiosources actually are running before timeSinceLastLoop starts counting or how I could fix it if that was the case.
I was also having another issue where setting playOnAwake to true on each of the audiosources rather than using the play() method inside of my createNewAudioSource method would result in no sound playing at all. Maybe that could be related to this?

Instead of destroying and recreating sources in order to loop why not simply call Play again? If AudioSource.clip is set to the same clip that is playing then the clip will sound like it is re-started. sounds exactly like what you would want

Each song starts playing again with a new audiosource at 57.3 seconds, but the original song still continues to play for a bit because they have a few notes finishing.

Using 2 sources would likely help resolve this issue, since you wont be dealing with destroying sources (which could cause the issue you stated).  It would also make debugging the issues easier because you no longer need indexing and the sources will persist.

The issue happens before any source is destroyed and I need indexing so I can switch between multiple tracks smoothly. I'll try this later just to be absolutely sure but I think you've both misunderstood the problem. My script seems to be mistiming the song, with the ending of the first play not aligning with the start of the second despite the timer variable showing the correct time and any loop playing after doing it correctly. What I'm assuming the problem is at the moment is the timer not being synced up with the start of the first play, but I don't know why that would happen.

Can you try to delay the start of the first loop to frame 2 or 3 instead of starting it in Awake? There is a small chance that Time.deltaTime is too large in the first frame.

Doing this helped close the gap but it still sounds janky on the first loop. This time it kind of sounded like the start of the second loop started too early. I tried changing it to start on frame 1000 and tried with and without waiting until the next frame to start adding Time.deltaTime but the result was the same. Although I did notice that the entire game paused briefly when starting the first loop, but only on the first loop. I tried selecting the preload audio data on each track to help with this but no luck.

I just tried making an audiosource for each song and using PlayOneShot instead of deleting and making new ones but no luck, same results. However going back to what I had before and waiting to start on a later frame only using one song for everything did stop the game from having that lagspike and make it loop fine.

For anyone in the future, I was able to get around this problem by using the current time of one of the audiosources rather than a separate timer
